# Reference the View from ViewModel while using DataTemplate for the ViewModel

Tags: wpf, datatemplate

i'm using a DataTemplate to provide the association of View to ViewModel, for example:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type viewModels:SomeViewModel}">
    <views:SomeView />
</DataTemplate>
```

now i need to reference the View somehow in my ViewModel, so i could reference some control directly by its name.
Is there anyway to do that?

- **Note**
  i already tried to add a SomeView parameter to the SomeViewModel Ctor but than the SomeView Ctor is being invoked twice(one for the instance i sent to the SomeViewModel Ctor and the because of the framework i guess...)

thanks for your help

Comment: Then you are not using MVVM if you want to reference the View in the ViewModel and i cannot recommend to do it that way. I would use the codebehind files of your `SomeView` to access and update the controls based on ViewModel-Properties or to update ViewModel-Properties based on control values, if you cannot use Binding directly.

Comment: Please try and explain your full need here so we can give you a better solution using the MVVM way. If you don`t want to use MVVM fully, then simply catch the view onload event and in the code behind set "this.DataContext.SomeViewModelSomeProperty = this.WhateverControl"

Comment: i know this is not MVVm anymore when i'm trying to reference the view in my viewmodel, there is a specific situation that i need to tight up the view to the viewmodel,  is there a way to that?

Comment: What do you specifically want to do?

Comment: there is a content control that displays view according to the current view model.
to simplify - think i have 2 buttons, when i press on the first one it creates viewmodel1 and sets it as the contentcontrol content dp and when i press the second button it creates viewmodel2 and so on. my problem is that i have no choice but to associate a control in one of my views, but since the datatemplate is doing the associating between the view and viewmodel i can't pass the view/one of its control in the viewmodel's ctor.
is it clear enough?

Comment: Please see my earlier [`answer`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22318576/wpf-viewmodel-hosting). In this situation, using `DataTemplateSelector` that returns the desired `ViewModel` depending on the type.

Comment: not the right direction... i have no problem with the template itself, think of it as a situation(a very unhealthy one...) where u want to pass the template to the type ctor

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you're looking for:

```
public partial class SomeView : UserControl
{
    public SomeView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.Loaded += View_Loaded;
    }

    void SomeView_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var someViewModel = (SomeViewModel)this.DataContext;
        someViewModel.View = this;
    }
}
```